# Why win the jump ball?

Tags: basketball, nba

In basketball, why win the opening jump ball if there's no advantage (possession will be rotated afterwards).

Comment: You specifically are asking about the NBA, right, and not NCAA or others?

Comment: Mainly NBA, passing interest in the NCAA.

Comment: NCAA of course has a specific advantage, as they don't have jump balls after the initial: they have a possession arrow, so the winner of the initial jump gets either equal or one more possession.

Comment: I recall coming across a piece by some sportswriter, who claimed that it is better to start the 4th quarter with the ball (which is what happens if you win the jump ball, at least in the NBA).

Answer (score 3):

Because you want the extra possession in the 4th quarter.

> The team that gains possession after the opening tap will put the ball into play at their opponent’s end line to begin the fourth period. The team losing the opening tap will put the ball into play at their opponent’s end line at the beginning of the second and third quarters.

[NBA Rules History](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_history.html)

Note for NCAA and lower - Jump ball is very important because all possessions are alternating including jump ball situations and second half possession.  Original basketball rules settled things with a jump ball.  Possession arrow was something to make things go faster and to be fairer to smaller teams (and to get rid of referees having issues throwing a good, fair ball for jumps).

Comment: Could you provide some evidence showing that one extra possession is a significant advantage?

Comment: You don't get an extra possession in the 4th,  since it alternates. You would actually get your posession in the third, which seems to be a disadvantage (if any, like @PhilipKendall states).

Comment: It doesn't need a stats advantage at all.   NBA coaches are all about the 4th quarter.  If an NBA coach wants the extra possession in the 4th he wants his big to win the tip.  The big doesn't care if there is a stats advantage, he does what his coach wants.  So his advantage is a happy coach.

Comment: @StackOverflowed - No.  Loser gets ball in 2nd and 3rd quarters.  Can't ever remember NBA having alternating quarters.

Comment: And I am sure there is some SLOAN data that says if the game is tied that the team with first possession in the 4th quarter wins 53% of the time...

Comment: @Coach-D Sorry I might be misinformed, I just read this somewhere: "It should be pointed out however that the opening tip of a game really is a formality with no advantage to the team winning it since possessions are alternated for the remaining quarters with a new jump for any overtime period." http://www.82games.com/random14.htm

Comment: @Coach-D but how much advantage does potentially having one extra possession leading up to the 4th quarter give to a team? If it's around 3% or so, then it all cancels out.

Comment: @StackOverflowed - Added link to answer.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Like I said coaches want the ball to start the 4th.  If there was a poll to all NBA coaches asking them if they want to win the tip 100% will say yes.   You would never be able to infer an advantage of a tip with stats.  Because given that you have a dominant big man that can win tips would probably mean you have slightly better chance of winning the game.  I would guess that the tip winner has won at least 51% of those games but that may have nothing to do with winning the tip.

Comment: I think you're right at the end of the day, but I don't find guessing that statistics exist nor the opinion of NBA coaches (see: NFL coaches and going for 2 or going for 4th and 1) as useful contributions.

Comment: @Joe - First there is a correlation between tips won and winning the game.  I suggested the "tip" cannot be an inferred basis because it takes an athlete on your team to win the tip.  If each team had a designated "tip guy" and he could not play then we would know for sure.  There is hard correlation on any bball stats website that performance in the 4th quarter far outweighs the other three in win correlation.  There is also strong correlation that having an extra possession increases chances of winning quarter.  Also happy coach is a good thing right?

Comment: What I'm saying is that all you have provided is words: what would be better is actual statistics.  A link to a study.  Actual data, that sort of thing.  Without that, your answer feels right, but it's just guesswork.

Comment: @Joe - You have to understand that this would be a tremendous amount of work.  For instance you would have to throw out a huge subset of games because they may be completely over (95%+ win expectancy) by the time the 4th hits, then you have the best big factor getting the jump and 10-20 other variables.  Just to see if you should win the tip?  Nobody will put that much work in.  As for win% the heaviest correlation is in the 1st quarter.  Not because great teams play better in the first, they simply play their starters more and then less during blowout time.

Comment: That's fine, but what I'm saying is you keep saying "stats would show" without providing stats.  Don't say "stats would show..." if you don't have the stats, it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

No real reason; as you say possession will be rotated afterwards. Probably the biggest advantage is the psychological benefit of having the first possession and thus the first opportunity to take a lead, but I imagine that's a *very* minor benefit.